# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find ModelName with ID= when using accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, accepts-nested-attributes

For example, I have three model classes:

```
class Promotion < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :promotion_sets, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :promotion_sets
end

class PromotionSet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :promotion
  has_many :promotion_set_details, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :promotion_set_details
end

class PromotionSetDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :promotion_set
end
```

I want to insert. For example here is my code:

```
  Promotion.create(id: 999)
  promotion.promotion_sets
   .create(prepare_promotion_set_attrs(attributes['promotion_sets']))
```

Then those are methods for preparing children attributes:

```
def prepare_promotion_set_attrs(set_attrs)
  promotion_sets_attributes = []
  set_attrs&.each do |attr|
    promotion_sets_attributes.push(
      id:  123456,
      promotion_set_details_attributes: prepare_promotion_set_details_attrs(attr['set_details'])
    )
  end

  promotion_sets_attributes
end

def prepare_promotion_set_details_attrs(set_detail_attrs)
  promotion_set_details_attributes = []
  set_detail_attrs&.each do |attr|
    promotion_set_details_attributes.push(
      # sample fields here
    )
  end
```

This insert is successfully execute. But when I move insert code from  inserting outside to `accepts_nested_attributes_for` for only class Promotion:

```
Promotion.create(
        id: 999,
        promotion_sets_attributes: prepare_promotion_set_attrs(some_data),
      )
# not use this 
# promotion.promotion_sets
#   .create(prepare_promotion_set_attrs(attributes['promotion_sets']))
```

I meet exception:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find PromotionSet with
>   ID=123456 for Promotion with ID=999

I cannot explain why. And I don't know why this is just only happen for class Promotion but class PromotionSet can insert using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` without any error.

Comment: Isn't your `PromotionSet` model missing `belongs_to :promotion`? Try adding it.

Comment: @Pavan I have added. but error still same.

Comment: @Pavan I have added in my question. Please take a look